# Django - how to render a file structure beautifully?

Tags: python, html, django

using the function below in views.py, i can generate the contents/structure of a folder, given a file_path:

[the function basically returns a list that contains strings, if you don't wanna read the code and want to see what the strings look like check the next 2 images]

```
def XML_files_structure(startpath):
    lst = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startpath):
        level = root.replace(startpath, '').count(os.sep)
        indent = ' ' * 4 * (level)
        lst.append(indent + os.path.basename(root) + '/')
        subindent = ' ' * 4 * (level + 1)
        for f in files:
            lst.append(subindent + f)
    return lst
```

In my template, i have the HTML code:

```
<ul>
 {% for str in data.file_structure %}
  <pre> {{str}} </pre>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

which generates the following on my webpage

[image]

This kind of structure is indeed what I'd like. But i feel like I'm doing it in a very inefficient way, and also the final result is ugly and not very user friendly. I'd like to add the functionality you have in the windows explorer - the ability to open and close up the contents of a folder.

How would you do this in Django or HTML?

Answer (score 1):

The `lst` can save each file/folder with their level as tubles `(level, filename)`:

```
def XML_files_structure(startpath):
    lst = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startpath):
        level = root.replace(startpath, '').count(os.sep)
        lst.append((level, os.path.basename(root) + '/'))

        for f in files:
            lst.append((level+1, f))

    return lst
```

Example output:

```
lst = [(1, "XML_files/"), (2, "txt_f1.txt"), (2, "fol_1/"), (3, "txt_f2.txt"), (3, "txt_f3.txt")]
```

Then you can add the indentation inside the for loop in the HTML template.

It will allow you to change how the file structure looks from inside the template (using javascript framworks, CSS, etc.) without changing the `XML_files_structure` function.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I don't know how i could get the windows explorer functionality if I went with this approach

Comment: What do you mean by "windows explorer functionality" ?

Comment: you could click on "fol_1/" or an arrow next to it, to make the contents of that folder show up or hide

Comment: I think you can still do that using my solution.